# Why doesn't async work in Aiohttp ClientSession test Fastapi, also the time is too long for multiple requests?

Tags: aiohttp

I want to test Asynchronous code FastAPI with Aiohttp. I have an API that creates the object in Postgresql with Sqlalchemy, I want to send the request through a JSON file and check API with lots of requests, I don't have any error, but there are two problems:
1- async doesn't work
2- response time is too long
would you please check my code?

**API**

```
@router.post("/city/", response_model=city_base_Response_model)
async def create_city(city: city_create_model, request: Request):
    [requestedBy, APIKEY] = await api_honesty(request, inspect.stack()[0][3])
    city_obj = await get_city_by_name(city_name=city.city_name)
    if city_obj:
        return response_body(False, status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, message()['OBJECT_IS_ALREADY_EXIST'], None)
    try:
        city_obj = await insert_city(city=city, requestedBy=requestedBy)
        await get_log(data=jsonable_encoder(city), requestedBy=requestedBy, fun_name=inspect.stack()[0][3], object=city_obj.id)
        return response_body(True, status.HTTP_200_OK, message()['ACTION_DONE_SUCCESSFULLY'], {**city.dict(), "id": city_obj.id})
    except Exception as exception:
        logging.error(exception)
        return response_body(False, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message()['ACTION_FAILD'], None)
```

**aiohttp**

```
start_time = datetime.now()

async def create(url,session, data):
    async with session.post(
        url,
        headers ={'Content-Type': 'application/json','api_key':'****'},
        json=data
        )as response:
        print("StartTime",":" + " " + str(datetime.now()))
        Status = response.status
        print(f'EndTime : {datetime.now()} ---- Status {str(response.status)}')
        return Status

async def main(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with aiofiles.open('data_create.json', 'r') as f:
            contents = await f.read()
            objects = json.loads(contents)
            for row in objects:
                results = await asyncio.gather(*[create(urls,session, row)], return_exceptions=True)
            return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls="http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/"
    asyncio.run(main(urls))
    print("--- %s  requests is completed  seconds ---" % (datetime.now() - start_time))
```

for 50 requests,JSON file is a list of 50 dict data,async doesn't work

```
.
.
.
StartTime : 2022-07-25 11:59:35.662056
EndTime : 2022-07-25 11:59:35.662079 ---- Status 200
StartTime : 2022-07-25 11:59:35.880552
EndTime : 2022-07-25 11:59:35.880577 ---- Status 200
--- 0:00:15.970023  requests is completed  seconds ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `asyncio.gather` is to run several coroutines in parallel, but
in your `main` function, when you are running

```py
for row in objects:
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[create(urls,session, row)], return_exceptions=True)
```

you're awaiting each call to the `create` function individually, since you're `await`ing once per loop. So, you're running your requests sequentially. To run them concurrently, try changing it to

```py
results = await asyncio.gather(
    *(create(urls,session, row) for row in objects),
    return_exceptions=True
)
```

Also, in your `create` function, the call `print("StartTime",":" + " " + str(datetime.now()))` is **after** `session.post`, meaning you're not timing the time the HTTP request takes, only the time it takes Python to lookup the `status` attribute. You probably want to move that to the line before `async with session.post(...)`.